# objective-C: how to access variable from a separate instance of the same class?

Tags: objective-c

I have a code that saves some data in the first instance that is run. However, the second instance of this class calls a different method and instead need to print out this data from the first instance. I've tried extern and static and both aren't working. Is this possible?

code.h:

> ```
> extern NSString GlobalID
> @interface ...
> @end
> ```

code.m:

```
#import code.h
    @implementation NSString *GlobalID;
    -dostuff1: {GlobalID=@"text"}
    -dostuff2:  {NSLog(@"%@",GlobalID)}

    @end
```

Comment: I think you are confused. Using an instance variable (a synthesized property) means that each instance has its own value. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I need to get a particular value from one instance to another. Would this work if it was between instances of different classes?

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for isn't an instance variable. You want a global class variable. those can be created like this:

```
// code.m
#import "code.h"

static NSString *global_string = nil;
@implementation code
...
@end
```

then you can just edit `global_string` from anywhere in the class.

the keyword `static` means that the variable is only created once and will retain it's value between instances and just about everything else. the keyword `extern` is used when you want to refer to a global (non-static) variable in a different module. Note that a `static` variable cannot be `extern` and vice-versa, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work either, I set the static variable in one  method and print its value in another. I call the first method in one instance, the second in another.